# Typescript: Type-safe way of transforming data from an object type to union type

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, mapped-types, data-transform

I'm looking for a type-safe way of performing a data transformation of the following type:

```js
// original data type
const nameToDaysAsWWEChamp = {
  "Stone Cold Steve Austin": 529,
  "The Rock": 378,
  "Hulk Hogan": 2188,
  "Ric Flair": 118,
} as const;

// target data type
type TargetType =
  | { name: "Stone Cold Steve Austin"; daysAsWWEChamp: 529 }
  | { name: "The Rock"; daysAsWWEChamp: 378 }
  | { name: "Hulk Hogan"; daysAsWWEChamp: 2188 }
  | { name: "Ric Flair"; daysAsWWEChamp: 118 };


// attempted transformation
function f(name: keyof typeof nameToDaysAsWWEChamp): TargetType {
  return { name, daysAsWWEChamp: nameToDaysAsWWEChamp[name] }; // error!
}
```

The function `f` wants to return an object of the following type:

```
{
    name: "Stone Cold Steve Austin" | "The Rock" | "Hulk Hogan" | "Ric Flair";
    daysAsWWEChamp: 529 | 378 | 2188 | 118;
}
```

How can I convince typescript to "respect the mapping" and narrow the return type of `f` to `TargetType`?

Comment: You could do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo83gw), but I'm not sure how to cleanly make TypeScript "respect the mapping", so for now, I've just used an assertion.

Comment: This is essentially the issue in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended refactoring at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBJ2xN). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what I want!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can't abstract over the body of `f` to understand that every possible narrowing of `name` to a particular member of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `keyof typeof nameToDaysAsWWEChamp` will result in a valid `TargetType` when output as `{name, daysAsWWEChamp: nameToDaysAsWWEChamp[name]}`.  It doesn't try to analyze it like that at all; instead it just takes the type of `name` as the union, and therefore that `daysAsWWEChamp` is also a union, and results in the too-wide type you mentioned.  It doesn't understand that the union type of `name` is *correlated* with the union type of `daysAsWWEChamp`.

This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); TypeScript doesn't really support correlated union types.  The suggested approach in cases like this is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)... it involves using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of unions.  You have to refactor your types so that operations are seen as generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  You can read the issue for a detailed description of this.  For your example it looks like this:

```
// this just makes it easier to refer to the type
type NameToDaysAsWWEChamp = typeof nameToDaysAsWWEChamp;

type TargetType<K extends keyof NameToDaysAsWWEChamp = keyof NameToDaysAsWWEChamp> =
    { [P in K]: { name: P, daysAsWWEChamp: NameToDaysAsWWEChamp[P] } }[K];
```

Here `TargetType` is now a generic *distributive object type*. If you specify the generic type argument as some particular key of `NameToDaysAsWWEChamp`, you get the corresponding member of your original `TargetType` union.  And if you specify a *union*, you get the corresponding union out also.  If you don't specify it at all, you get the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of the full `keyof NameToDaysAsWWEChamp`, and therefore it's the same as your old `TargetType`.  That means in some sense `TargetType` is the same as it was before:

```
type Same = TargetType;
/* type Same = {
    name: "Stone Cold Steve Austin";
    daysAsWWEChamp: 529;
} | {
    name: "The Rock";
    daysAsWWEChamp: 378;
} | {
    name: "Hulk Hogan";
    daysAsWWEChamp: 2188;
} | {
    name: "Ric Flair";
    daysAsWWEChamp: 118;
} */
```

But now it has the ability to be given a restricted type argument.  And now, finally, we can write `f` as a *generic* function that takes a `name` argument of type `K` and returns an output of type `TargetType<K>`:

```
function f<K extends keyof NameToDaysAsWWEChamp>(name: K): TargetType<K> {
    return { name, daysAsWWEChamp: nameToDaysAsWWEChamp[name] }; // okay
}
```

This works because the compiler sees the output as `{ name: K, daysAsWWEChamp: NameToSaysAsWWEChamp[K] }`, which is the same as the definition `TargetType<K>` (at least for `K` that is a single literal type; it's a bit more complicated for unions, and the compiler does some technically unsafe things, see [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730), but that's intentional and the behavior here is what you want).

And as an extra bonus, your `f()` function output will be more specific and narrower than just `TargetType`, and you can use these narrower types to your advantage if you want:

```
const hh = f("Hulk Hogan");
// const hh: { name: "Hulk Hogan"; daysAsWWEChamp: 2188; }

const mineral = f(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "The Rock" : "Stone Cold Steve Austin");
// const mineral: TargetType<"Stone Cold Steve Austin" | "The Rock">
if (mineral.daysAsWWEChamp === 378) {
    mineral.name;
    //      ^? (property) name: "The Rock"
} else {
    mineral.name;
    //      ^? (property) name: "Stone Cold Steve Austin"
}
```

The compiler knows that `hh` is a particular `TargetType` member, while `mineral` is one of a particular pair of members.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbApgFRAEXgTwgQQgHVCBRAYQAskAHGAXhgG8AoGNmAIgGUpxkYyIADYATGD2QA3fngCu0AJZgOALhgBWAEwBOADSt2HVBX4AlEMADWqmAGYA7AA597TgAlZQyzDcgA5vDKapoAjI7OBmwcpgrAMABiQvAKAE42IWH6AL4w8BAwoJBQANzMzFDY1PwAckhomDj4RKSUNPQwFVUgAGZwdehYuATE5FSI1KXllfyo8Cl+yFCo0wA8ANIwyAAeUMhgIvmWyNg9MLUoA43DLWO0DEcnvef1g00jreMAfPSRTDAA2gAFGBKGBrAC6akYfRQakBuhgIiuzVGNDUz0uQxRH2oQPBMByWX+EMm3VkYGAUAU4Bg3XWmx2ewOMAepwxDSx71unwAFAhYWCAJRqWbzRbLKrrb4sVwpRayFJgP785AIpGcm5omEvZFcmj-FX4rKlLJlTr8Lh1dqihZLaalAD0ACoOtNxFaGDL2Cq1NxeGB+IJROJdtIYHJFMpSq51W9NeM1FptCaYAAfJi-H2cYxmCzWaPsWPXVEJuxOFPpr1sLMcDxeHz+QIcAtsIvY27BMKOCsZ1w1mJxRLJNItxG6+PUNQZbvMHJOh1lQrQGAUCjtbo82ueby+ALKQWOh0FcDL1dQ7W+us7xtRscakuTmChcLFAmLk+wRBKZApeBCdc8gAsvAUAUAAdL++wgIgPKCjAKwwAADGB6gwAA-NmJgwOYVgcDAvo8HwAjCGIEhhhGVL7oex5FDAX4Br+QginMtoSsgKx+kRQakaGMjyJReHpkYWE4dYnzMAovQ8vRP5-mBbZ6uM9B0AwDiOHBVZ0d+jFgSqo4OkergwAAemhs6bEIED8JpMk6XpvwGUZJlmVkQA)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

// attempted transformation

```
function f(name: keyof typeof nameToDaysAsWWEChamp):TargetType {
    return { name, daysAsWWEChamp: nameToDaysAsWWEChamp[name] } as TargetType;
}
```

Comment: I’m looking for an alternative to this!